# Почему функция выводит все значения вместо выбранных в checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

По задумке функция должна выводить значения только выбранных чекбоксов, но почему-то выводит все.

Почему и как исправить?

На [codepen](https://codepen.io/RJDio/pen/yLNodaL).

```js
let checkBox1 = document.querySelector('#checkBox1');
let checkBox2 = document.querySelector('#checkBox2');
let checkBox3 = document.querySelector('#checkBox3');
let form4 = document.querySelector('#form4');
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes');

checkBox1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(checkBox2.checked = true){
        checkBox2.checked = false;
    }
});
checkBox2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(checkBox1.checked = true){
        checkBox1.checked = false;
    }
});

form4.onchange = function(){
    for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        if(checkboxes[i].cheked = true){
        let checkboxVal = checkboxes[i].value;
            alert(checkboxVal);
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<form  id="form4" class="configurator-form-1" autocomplete="off">
  <input value="Заказать гидрофикацию" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="checkBox1"> <label class="configurator-checkbox-label" for="label">Заказать гидрофикацию</label>
  <input value="Гидрофикация не требуется" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="checkBox2" > <label class="configurator-checkbox-label" for="label1">Гидрофикация не требуется</label>
  <input value="Требуется дополнительный опциональный комплект"  class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="checkBox3"> <label class="configurator-checkbox-label" for="label2">Требуется дополнительный опциональный комплект</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Две опечатки.

```
if (checkboxes[i].checked == true) {
```

Comment: Эх, опять я не успел ) Вы молодец, Igor.

Answer (score 4):

1. У Вас ошибка в `checked`
2. Проверка равенства производится через `==`

```js
    let checkBox1 = document.querySelector('#checkBox1');
    let checkBox2 = document.querySelector('#checkBox2');
    let checkBox3 = document.querySelector('#checkBox3');
    let form4 = document.querySelector('#form4');
    let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxes');

    checkBox1.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(checkBox2.checked = true){
            checkBox2.checked = false;
        }
    });
    checkBox2.addEventListener('click', function(){
        if(checkBox1.checked = true){
            checkBox1.checked = false;
        }
    });

    form4.onchange = function(){
        for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
            if(checkboxes[i].checked == true){
                let checkboxVal = checkboxes[i].value;
                alert(checkboxVal);
            }
        }
    };
```

```html
<form  id="form4" class="configurator-form-1" autocomplete="off">
  <input value="Заказать гидрофикацию" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="checkBox1"> <label class="configurator-checkbox-label" for="label">Заказать гидрофикацию</label>
  <input value="Гидрофикация не требуется" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="checkBox2" > <label class="configurator-checkbox-label" for="label1">Гидрофикация не требуется</label>
  <input value="Требуется дополнительный опциональный комплект"  class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" id="checkBox3"> <label class="configurator-checkbox-label" for="label2">Требуется дополнительный опциональный комплект</label>
</form>
```

Comment: @Dio Такое бывает ) Выберите лучше ответ Igor, как верный.

Comment: В любом случае и вам спасибо)